# How much can this c/c++ loop be optimized?

Tags: c++, c, performance, optimization, loops

I am a newbie on optimization. I have been reading some reference on how to optimize c++ code but I have a hard time applying it to real code. Therefore I just want to gather some real world optimization technique on how to squeeze as much juice from the CPU/Memory as possible from the loop below

```
double sum = 0, *array;
array = (double*) malloc(T * sizeof(double));
for(int t = 0; t < T; ++t){
sum += fun(a,b,c,d,e,f,sum);
*(array+t) = sum;
}
```

where `a,b,c,d,e,f` are `double` and `T` is `int`. Anything including but not limited to memory alignment, parallelism, openmp/MPI, and SSE instructions are welcome. Compiler is standard gcc, microsoft, or commonly available compiler. If the solution is compiler specific, please specific compiler and any option flag associate with your solution.

Thanks!

PS: Forgot to mention properties `fun`. Please assume that it is a simple function with no loop inside, and compose of only basic arithmetic operation. Simply think of it as an inline function.

EDIT2: since the details of `fun` is important, please forget the parameter c, d, e, f and assume `fun` is defined as

```
inline double fun(a,b, sum){
return sum + a* ( b - sum);
}
```

Comment: To optimize, you often need to know that a particular piece of code is worth optimizing.  Without knowing what fun(...) does or how big T can get in practical terms, this is not really a useful question.

Comment: The function call overhead will outweigh any loop optimisation (unless it is inlined). You are performing a micro-optimisation without first measuring.

Comment: Why use `*(array+t)` instead of the equivalent but clearer `array[t]`?

Comment: Writing unreadable code seems to keep one from being fired ;) This is not written by me so I do not know the reason.

Comment: Writing unreadable code *should* get you fired.  *sigh*

Comment: Has this code been profiled?  Do you know that the loop is the issue?  Do you know that fun() is not the issue?  Once you profile the code, you'll be better able to optimize.  If you don't profile, then your "optimizations" are SWAGs.

Comment: I have profiled the code. The time is mostly spent on `fun`. It is usually composed of basic arithmetic operations so I made it generic. This post is more for different technique I can use after I profile the code. :)

Comment: @leon: `a` is a function pointer? Or are you missing a `*`?

Comment: Why downvote this post?  Are people really that out of touch with reality to think that all optimization is premature?

Comment: The usage of a,b,c,d,e,f is not shown. Does fun() modify them? You can't talk about optimizing code without showing the code.

Comment: @John Dibling - yes, I find that people who know optimization know to "find the right algorithm" first and take it as given. Others just babble O(N) and think all low level optimization is premature and anyone looking to do it is stupid.

Comment: @phkahler the function `fun` is shown. Moreover, the purpose of this post is low level optimization and not choosing algorithm. Choosing algorithm is my job (as a mathematican). So you can assume that the optimal algorithm is chosen if you want to suggest a solution

Comment: If this is C, don't cast the return value of `malloc` -- it's not needed, and using casts silences valuable compiler warnings. If it's C++, the cast is required -- but you should be using `new` and not `malloc` anyway.

Comment: [don't tag both C and C++](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252430/995714). [In C you don't cast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `sum` depends on its previous values in a non-trivial way, it is impossible to parallelize the code (so OpenMP and MPI are out).

Memory alignment and SSE should be enforced/used automatically with appropriate compiler settings.

Besides inlining `fun` and unrolling the loop (by compiling in `-O3`) there is not much we can do if `fun` is completely general.

---

Since `fun(a,b,sum) = sum + a*(b-sum)`, we have the closed form

```
            ab             t+1
array[t] = ———— ( 1 - (2-a)    )
            a-1
```

which can be vectorized and parallelized, but the division and exponentiation can be very expensive.

Nevertheless, with the closed form we can start the loop from any index, e.g. create 2 threads one from t = 0 to T/2-1, another from t = T/2 to T-1, which perform the original loop, but the initial `sum` is computed using the above closed form solution. Also, if only a few values from the array is needed this can be computed lazily.

And for SSE, you could first fill the array first with `(2-a)^(t+1)`, and then apply `x :->  x - 1` to the whole array, and then apply `x :-> x * c` to the whole array where `c = a*b/(1-a)`, but there may be [automatic vectorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_vectorization#Automatic_vectorization) already.

Comment: How can you algebraically manipulate fun(a,b,sum) when he didn't tell us what it does?

Comment: It'd be good to put some numbers on "very expensive"--generally, I find division about 5x as expensive as multiplication, and exponentiation about 50x as expensive.

Comment: Note that `a-1` is a constant, and a double. Hence `1/(a-1)` can be precomputed. Exponentiation is to a power of t, which is constant and thus takes O(log t). Still makes the whole calculation O(T log T) though.

Answer (score 3):

Unless fun() is very trivial - in which case consider inline, it is likely to dominate anything else you can do to the loop.

You probably want to look at the algorithm inside fun()

Answer (score 3):

The code you have above is about as fast as you can make it.

- Memory alignment is normally handled well enough by malloc anyway.
- The code cannot be parallelized because `f` is a function of previous sums (so you can't break up the computation into chunks).
- The computations are not specified so it's unclear whether SSE or CUDA or anything like that would be applicable.
- Likewise, you can't perform any useful loop-unrolling based on the properties of `f` because we don't know what it does.

(Stylistically, I'd use `array[t]` since it's clearer what's going on and it is no slower.)

---

Edit: now that we have `f(a,b,sum) = sum + a*(b-sum)`, we can try loop unrolling by hand to see if there's some pattern.  Like so (where I'm using `**` to mean "to the power of"):

```
sum(n) = sum(n-1) + sum(n-1) + a*(b-sum(n-1)) = (2-a)*sum(n-1) + a*b
sum(n) = (2-a)*( (2-a)*sum(n-2) + a*b ) + a*b
. . .
sum(n) = a*b*(2-a)**n + a*b*(2-a)**(n-1) + ... + a*b
sum(n) = a*b*( (2-a)**0 + (2-a)**1 + ... + (2-a)**n )
```

Well, now, isn't that interesting!  We've converted from a recurrent formula to a geometric series!  And, you may recall that the geometric series

```
SUM( x^n , n = 0..N ) = (x**(n+1) - 1) / (x - 1)
```

so that

```
sum(n) = a*b*( (pow(2-a,n+1) - 1) / (1-a) )
```

Now that you've done that math, you can start in on the sum anywhere you want (using the somewhat expensive pow computation).  If you have M free processors, and your array is long, you can split it into M equal pieces, use the above computation to find the first sum, and then use the recurrence formula you were using before (with the function) to fill the rest in.

At the very least, you could calculate a*b and 2-a separately and use those instead of the existing function:

```
sum = ab + twonega*sum
```

That cuts the math in your inner loop in half, approximately.

Answer (score 3):

one (very) minor optimization that can be done is:

```
double sum = 0, *array;   
array = (double*) malloc(T * sizeof(double));
double* pStart = array;
double* pEnd = array + T;
while(pStart < pEnd)
{
    sum += fun(a,b,c,d,e,f,sum); 
    *pStart++ = sum; 
}
```

this eliminates the addition of t to array for every iteration of the loop, the incrementation of t is replaced by the incrementation of pStart, for small sets of iterations(think less than 3, in that case the loop should be derolled), there is no real gain. the compiler should do this automatically, but sometimes it needs a little encouragement.

also depending on the size ranges of T it might be possible to gain performance by using a variable sized array(which would be stack allocated) or aligned _alloca

Comment: many processors do not actually add the T before the store they use register indirect which performs the add while executing the instruction all within the clock cycle  str r1,[r2,r3].  so it can be a wash.  some processors the destroyed moving pointer is faster

Comment: of course you could do a str r1,[r2],#8 (using ARM as an example) and do the destroyed pointer with its increment in one instruction where the register indirect takes two.  In general the pointer solution and indexed array solutions are a wash performance wise unless you target a specific processor, the indexed array solution is easier to read and maintain for most folks.  all we are doing is savin gone maybe two instructions here, fun() plus the setup for the call will dominate the time consumed.

Answer (score 2):

Accept @KennyTM's answer.  He is wrong to state that the computation is not parallelisable, as he goes on to show.  In showing that you can rewrite your recurrence relation in closed form he illustrates a very general principle of optimising programs -- choose the best algorithm you can find and implement that.  None of the micro-optimisations that the other answers suggest will come close to computing the closed form and spreading the computation across many processors in parallel.

And, lest anyone offer the suggestion that this is just an example for learning parallelisation, I contend that @KennyTM's answer still holds good -- don't learn to optimise fragments of code, learn to optimise computations.  Choose the best algorithm for your purposes, implement it well and only then worry about performance.

Comment: +1 but I think that "Choose the best algorithm for your purposes, implement it well and only then worry about performance." is misleading.  After all, the whole reason why we select the best algorithm is because we are worried about performance.

Comment: Given the costs of exponentiation, you'd need 100+ processors to exceed the throughput of one if you split it up in the naive way.  You don't want the closed form--you want to _initialize_ with the closed form but otherwise use the recurrence which updates >50x faster.

Comment: @Rex - Indeed, I just think that many people hide behind the mantra of "premature optimization is the root of all evil" to chide *all* attempts at optimization, not just micro-optimization.  @Mark - It is easy to utilize many hundreds of cores by simply porting to CUDA.

Comment: @HPM: Yes; I hinted at this in my answer to the question, and I also have access to 100+ processors.  But I might want to use my 100+ processors for something that requires 100+ processors instead of something that doesn't.  @John: Indeed, and people also hide behind the "go away and use a profiler" answer too often also.  Good advice, yes, but it's not the _only_ good advice.

Comment: @HFM The intend of this post is for me to learn low level optimization. The recurrent function relation in my problem is often more complex than this and I, who has a mathematical background, always try to find a better formula for that. This question was made to be generic so that people can discuss low level optimization technique that one might be able to use. I am not asking for a solution to this specific problem but a set of techniques that I can use to make my code after after profiling. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at callgrind, part of the [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) toolset.  Run your code through that and see if anything sticks out as taking an unusually large amount of time.  Then you'll know what needs optimizing.  Otherwise, you're just guessing, and you (as well as the rest of us) will likely guess wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I would enable vector processing on the compiler. You could rewrite the code to open up the loops but the compiler will do it for you. If it is a later version.

You could use t+array as the for loop increment... again the optimizer might do this.
means your array index won't use a multiply again optimizer might do this.

You could use the switch to dump the generated assembler code and using that see what  you can change in the code to make it run faster.

Comment: but `fun` is a function of `sum` such that it cannot be moved out of the loop.

Comment: I can't help but feel that this is where it can be optimized if only we knew what it did.

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple of suggestions that haven't come up yet. I'm a bit out of date when it comes to modern PC-style processors, so they may make no significant difference.

- Using `float` might be faster than `double` if you can tolerate the lower precision. Integer-based fixed point might be faster still, depending on how well floating point operations are pipelined.
- Counting down from `T` to zero (and incrementing `array` each iteration) might be slightly faster - certainly, on an ARM processor this would save one cycle per loop.

Comment: float and double ops are usually equally faster in today's FP ALU's... the savings usually come in higher cache hit rates :-)

Comment: I am in a field that float is not acceptable :(

Answer (score 1):

another very minor optimization would be to turn the for() into

`while (--T)`

as comparing with zero is usually faster than comparing two random integers.

Answer (score 0):

Following the excellent answer by @KennyTM, I'd say the fastest way to do it sequentially should be:

```
double acc = 1, *array;
array = (double*) malloc(T * sizeof(double));
// the compiler should be able to derive those constant expressions, but let's do it explicitly anyway
const double k = a*b/(a-1);
const double twominusa = 2 - a;
for(int t = 0; t < T; ++t){
    acc *= twominusa;
    array[t] = k*(1-acc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having the compiler unroll the loop, you could unroll the loop and and some data prefetching.  Search the web for *data driven design c++*.  Here is an example of loop unrolling and prefetching data:

```
double sum = 0, *array;
array = (double*) malloc(T * sizeof(double));

// Calculate the number iterations and the
//    remaining iterations.
unsigned int iterations = T / 4;
unsigned int remaining_iterations = T % 4;
double sum1;
double sum2;
double sum3;
double sum4;
double * p_array = array;
for(int t = 0; t < T; T += 4)
{
    // Do some data precalculation
    sum += fun(a,b,c,d,e,f,sum);
    sum1 = sum;
    sum += fun(a,b,c,d,e,f,sum);
    sum2 = sum;
    sum += fun(a,b,c,d,e,f,sum);
    sum3 = sum;
    sum += fun(a,b,c,d,e,f,sum);
    sum4 = sum;
    // Do a "block" transfer to the array.
    p_array[0] = sum1;
    p_array[1] = sum2;
    p_array[2] = sum3;
    p_array[3] = sum4;
    p_array += 4;
}
// Handle the few remaining calculations
for (t = 0; t < remaining_iterations; ++t)
{
    sum += fun(a,b,c,d,e,f,sum);
    p_array[t] = sum;
}
```

The big hit here is the call to the `fun` function.  There are hidden setup and restore instructions involved when executing a function.  Also, the call forces a branch which will cause instruction pipelines to be flushed and reloaded (or cause to processor to waste time in branch prediction).

Another time performance hit is the number of variables passed to the function.  These variables have to be placed on the *stack* and copied into the function, which takes time.

Comment: I thought that the loop unrolling was done by the compilers today :-) plus, your manual unrolling still has data dependencies that could be alleviated with a more filled pipeline if you'd left the store operations interleaved.

Comment: The function can be inlined and thus will have no negative impact on performance.

Answer (score 0):

Many computers have a dedicated [multiply-accumulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply-accumulate) unit implemented in the processor's hardware.  Depending on your ultimate algorithm and target platform, you may be able to use this if the compiler isn't already using it when it optimizes.

Answer (score 0):

The following may not be worth it, but ....

The routine fun() takes seven (7) parameters.

Changing the order of the parameters to fun (sum, a, b, c, d, e, f) could help, IF the compiler can take advantage of the following scenario.  Parameters  through  appear to be invariant, and only  appears to be changing at this level in the code.  As parameters are pushed onto the stack in C/C++ from right to left, if parameters  through  truly are invariant, then the compiler could in theory optimize the pushing of the stack variables.  In other words,  through  would only need to be pushed onto the stack once, and  could in theory be the only parameter pushed and popped while in the loop.

I do not know if the compiler would take advantage of such a scenario, but I am tossing it out there as a possibility.  Disassembling could verify it as true or false, and profiling would indicate how much of a benefit that may be if true.